# Is there a javascript code to locate and highlight a block in a web page corresponding to its dom tree node?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here I have a dom tree parsed from a html page. I want to select a node in the tree, and highlight its corresponding area in the web page (just like google chrome does, illustrated in the image below). Is there any javascript code to implement this? I tried to wrap the selected tag with a  tag, but there are some cases it didn't work. What I need is a general way. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Does it have to highlight, or can it just outline it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a div overlay.

So you'd need to get the node's width, height and offset top and left and then overlay that with a div that has a semi-transparent background-image.

Should be fairly easy to do with jQuery

Comment: You mean make the selected tag as the child of a <div> tag, and put the <div> where the selected tag is in the dom tree? I've tried that, but in this case: <nobr><a>...</a><a>...</a></nobr>, if I selected <a> tag, wrapping it with a <div> tag, its content becomes an individual line in the web page, different as before.

Comment: @quantity I mean inserting a <div> tag right after the opening <body> tag. Set that div as position:absolute; and then position it top:; left:; width:; and height:; to the top and left offset and width & height of the node. Although would that cause problems with your dom tree?

Comment: I'll try that. What if there's no <body> tag in the html page? And I need to remove the highlighting if I de-select the tag. Can I still achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if there's no body tag. Just inject it at the start of the document if you can. It'll be fine if you set a top and left css style to it. Yes you can remove the div when you're finished, or set css `display:none;` and then show it by `display:block;` when you want.

Comment: How can I set position and size with javascript? I just use: var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); newDiv.style.position="absolute"; newDiv.style.left=this.offsetLeft;newDiv.style.top=this.offsetTop; newDiv.style.width=this.offsetWidth; newDiv.style.height=this.offsetHeight; document.body.appendChild(newDiv);  It just doesn't work!

Comment: @quantity Try this: `newDiv.style.left=this.offsetLeft+'px';` also add the `+'px'` to the `offsetTop`, `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`